# Libreoffice converting word to pdf issue

Tags: libreoffice

I am facing issue when converting microsoft word to PDF.
When I am converting word file to PDF with the help of libreoffice from command line command, there issue with the content in converted PDF file.

The background of the page in word resized and position of ellipse is changed.

Please find attached sample screen shot of word file(word.png) which I am trying to convert into PDF and PDF(pdf.png) in which I am facing issue.
Command which I am using,

> libreoffice --headless --convert-to html WORDFILE.docx

[image: screen shot of word file]

[image: screen shot of pdf file]

Comment: Does the same problem happen if you open the file in LibreOffice?

Comment: Convert to HTML (as in your command line) or to PDF? How about saving to Writer's `odt` format, first, then converting?

Comment: I am converting word into PDF. I have tried by converting first into odt and then convert it into PDF but same issue.